# Login Failed due to Triger Execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Something! has happened and I cannot login anymore using SSMS to my local SQL Server Express and this is the error I get:

[image]

So I Googled it and found this website solution which I ran:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/27/sql-server-fix-error-17892-logon-failed-for-login-due-to-trigger-execution-changed-database-context-to-master/

But then this is the error I get:

[image]

I also tried and put my computer name instead of LocalHost in that command, but again same error.

Comment: Maybe I just uninstall SQL Express?

Comment: You should check the name of your trigger prior to drop it, now you are using the name of Pinal Dave's trigger. To find the name execute this: select *
from sys.server_triggers

Comment: @sepupic oh I see, OK but how do I run your select statement if I can't login to SQL Express to begin with ?

Comment: you are just logged on using DAC, I see it on your screenshot. Now paste the code and execute it

Comment: @sepupic Oh in SQLCMD ? Ok I ran it there, returned nothing, says no rows affected

Comment: I've noted only now that using sqlcmd you are logged on to the DEFAULT instance (that has no logon trigger). The server that gives you a problem with logon trigger is the NAMED instance, so when you use sqlcmd you should pass server name as ...\SQLEXPRESS, not localhost